# How to capture traffic details of GPRS connection?

Tags: java, networking

I have an application where I need to count accurately number of bytes uploaded and downloaded (on both window and linux palrforms) on GPRS connection (a ppp connection). The application is in java. However I doubt if I can do it in pure java. Mix of commandline and java is also OK. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can just open the pseudo-file `/proc/net/dev` for reading, and look for the line starting with the name of the PPP device that you're interested in (eg. `ppp0`, `ppp1`, ...).